# MariaDB: No selection using EXISTS if column has an index

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, exists

For the first time I encountered a problem using EXISTS which I do not conceive. I have a table with patiend id and consultation date and try to select those patients who have several records with the same consultation date:

```
-- total rows in vital: 732,527
-- number of rows after selection: 7,817
-- number of rows with multiple pat_id/kons_dt: 809
SELECT a.*
FROM emr.vital a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM (SELECT pat_id, kons_dt, COUNT(*)
                    FROM emr.vital b
                    GROUP BY pat_id, kons_dt
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                ) b
               WHERE a.pat_id = b.pat_id
          )
```

This gives me the following result (only the first 4 rows):

```
+--------+---------------+
| pat_id | kons_dt       |
+--------+---------------+
|  21384 | 2018-06-29    |
|  21384 | 2018-06-29    |
|  21888 | 2017-04-04    |
|  21888 | 2017-04-04    |
|  ...   | ...           |
+--------+---------------+
```

Table `emr.vital`has no index. If I add an index:

```
CREATE INDEX id ON emr.vital(pat_id);
```

and run the same code no record is selected. I tried to create an minimal example but didn't succeed to get the same results, that is, I got identical results for both cases with and without index.

Maybe the EXPLAIN extract can give some ideas:

**Without index:**

```
+----+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type  |    table    |  type  | possible_keys |     key      | key_len |    ref    |  rows  |              Extra              |
+----+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | a           | ALL    | \N            | \N           | \N      | \N        | 734988 | Using filesort                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2> | eq_ref | distinct_key  | distinct_key | 7       | func,func |      1 |                                 |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | <derived3>  | ALL    | \N            | \N           | \N      | \N        | 734988 |                                 |
|  3 | DERIVED      | b           | ALL    | \N            | \N           | \N      | \N        | 734988 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+--------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+-----------+--------+---------------------------------+
```

and **with index:**

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id |   select_type   |    table    |  type  | possible_keys |     key      | key_len |            ref             |  rows  |                    Extra                     |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY         | a           | ALL    | pat_id        | \N           | \N      | \N                         | 734988 | Using filesort                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY         | <subquery2> | eq_ref | distinct_key  | distinct_key | 4       | func                       |      1 |                                              |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED    | <derived3>  | ALL    | \N            | \N           | \N      | \N                         | 734988 |                                              |
|  3 | LATERAL DERIVED | b           | ref    | pat_id        | pat_id       | 5       | emr.a.pat_id               |      1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-----------------+-------------+--------+---------------+--------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Any help is appreciated.
Version of MariaDB: 10.4.8.

**Edit 1:** This is the structure of the original table without index on `pat_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE `vital` (
  `pat_id`        int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `kons_dt`       date DEFAULT NULL,
  `praxis_id`     int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex`           varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `doby`          smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age_y`         smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gewicht`       double DEFAULT NULL,
  `groesse`       double DEFAULT NULL,
  `bmi`           double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Comment: the select of the exists canbe redurced because you don't need any data from that table

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE vital;`

Comment: This would speed up the query: `INDEX(pat_id, kons_dt)`, perhaps significantly.

Comment: @Rick James: I added the table structure and number of rows of the table and selection. Concerning speeding up: thanks. Nevertheless, it is not the question of speed but that adding index to pat_id or combined pat_id/kons_dt the selection does not work. If I remove index I get the expected result. This is a strange behaviour a never encountered because index shoud speed up and not interfer in the selection logic.

Comment: You talk about adding `INDEX(id)`, yet there is no `id` in the table.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Rick James: Thanks and sorry, my fault. It should be written pat_id, not id. I corrected in my question. Query was done correctly with pat_id (otherwise it would give an error).

Answer (score 0):

You have a mystery.  If you can create a small dataset that shows the problem (and has no sensitive info), please file a bug report.

Meanwhile, give this a try:

```
SELECT  a.*
    FROM ( SELECT  DISTINCT pat_id
            FROM ( SELECT  pat_id, kons_dt
                    FROM  emr.vital b
                    GROUP BY  pat_id, kons_dt
                    HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1 
                 ) b
         ) c
    JOIN  emr.vital a USING(pat_id)
    WHERE  a.pat_id = c.pat_id ;
```

and have `INDEX(pat_id, kons_dt)`